# Exactly 6 integer solutions

Tags: diophantine-equations

I am trying to find the greatest value of $"c"$ for which $7x + 9y = c$ has exactly six solutions over positive integers.

My approach: Let one of the solution = $(a, b)$

General solution is $(a + 9t, b - 7t)$

For values t = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 we get 6 solutions.

Also $b - 7t$ should be positive.

So maximum value of $b$ is 41.

I am struck at this point how to find the maximum value of $a$ subject to the condition $7a + 9b = c$ is maximum.

Any help?

Comment: Why not substitute integer values  $> 6$ for $t$ in your formula for the general solution? One of $a,b$ is going to be negative anyway for large enough $c$

Comment: If $t \ge 6$ we get more than 6 solutions.

Comment: So  *exactly 6 solutions* is a myth.

Comment: Are you asking about POSITIVE solutions? If so, then edit your question.

Comment: @Piquito there are obviously infinite solutions if negative numbers are included. The OP should mention it though

Answer (score 1):

When you don´t restraint the values $(x,y)$ the general solution is given by $(x,y)=(a+9t,b-7t)$ and there are infinitely many solutions hence, in order to have exactly six solutions we take positive or non-negative ones. We take positive solutions.

It follows one can take the values $t=0,1,2,3,4,5$ so $7t\in\{0,7,14,21,28,35\}$ which implies $35\lt b\lt 42$. For each of these six values of $b$, we can take any $a$ so we get a value of $c$ and the equation admits exactly six positive solutions for all value of $a$, $b$ being fixed. It is clear that does not exist a maximum for $c$ because $a$ can be arbitrarily large.

But we can search a minimum $c$. Take $b=36$ and $a=1$; this gives the value
$$c=7 \cdot 1+9\cdot36=\color{red}{331}$$ and the equation $$7x+9y=331$$ which admits exactly the following six positive solutions:
$$(x,y)\in\{(1,36),(10,29),(19,22),(28,15),(37,8),(46,1)\}$$

Comment: Nice solution.  $c = 331$ is the minimum number satisfies the condition. But for $a = 8, b = 41$ we get maximum number which is $425$.  Why we have to choose $a = 8$? because $x$ ranges from $0$ to $8$.

Comment: What you say, dear friend, it is not true. If you take, for example, $b=36$ and $a$ positive arbitrary then you have exactly the following six positive solutions: $(a,36),(a+9,29),(a+18,22),(a+27,15),(a+36,8),(a+45,1)$. For other values of the parameter $t$ you get  non-positive solutions. But the value of $c$ has no upper bound being $c=7a+324$. Am I wrong?

Comment: Here $b-7t > 0$ So for values 0 to 5 we have six solutions. But for t = 6 where $7t$ is 42 we get 7 solutions.  So I took $t = 41$.  Subsequently, largest value of $a = 8$, we get the following solutions $(x,y)\in\{(8,41),(17,34),(26,27),(35,20),(44,13),(53,6)\}$.  So largest value of $c = 425$.  Oh, for a = 9, also we get 6 solutions.  Where $c = 432$

Comment: Yes I am wrong because with $a$ large, negative values of $t$ produce more than six positive solutions. It is interesting to see if your $425$ is actually the maximun. I bet that yes. Later I will see it.

Comment: @user97674: Yes it is the maximun!  Following the reasoning above $a$ can not be greater than $8$ (because if and $a\gt 9$ then we can take a negative value for the parameter $t$ yielding still a positive solutions besides of the six enumerated) and $b$ can not be greater than $41$. This gives for the constant $c$ your value $425$. In fact it is the required maximun.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed $x>0$ and $y>0$.

There are, IMHO, precisely 63 values of $c$ which give exactly six solutions.
The smallest is $c=331$, the maximum is $c=441$.
For $c=441$, $(x,y)=(9,42),(18,35),(27,28),(36,21),(45,14),(54,7)$

I found this with a simple program to calculate $c$ from $x$ and $y$ for a very generous $(x,y)$ range, accumulating the number of solution for each $c$ and retaining just the first values found for $(x,y)$.
Then I reran the program, writing out the $(c,x,y)$ values for the above range.

I found a clear pattern emerging from the results; the maximum number of solutions increases as $c$ grows, but that was not the question.

Although there is nothing wrong with using $(a,b,t)$, I could see no easy way to find the lowest $(a,b)$ values for a set.
Please let me know if you need any further details.

**Added 20 Sept 2016**

**I've noticed that exactly 6 solutions is not unique.
My data shows that, for exactly $N$ solutions, there are 63 values of $c$ for $N=2$ up to $N=300$**

Answer (score 0):

So, if (a,b) is a solution of $7x + 9y = c$
then $(a+n,b+m)$, with  $7n + 9m = 0$, is also a solution.
But this approach does not look promising.

A different way is to consider that
$$
\sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,c} {N(c)\,z^{\,c} }  = \frac{1}
{{\left( {1 - z^{\,7} } \right)\left( {1 - z^{\,9} } \right)}}
$$
with $N(c)$ indicating the number of non-negative solutions.
If you expand the RHS, you will notice that in order to get
exactly 6 solutions, $c$ will span from $315$ to $425$,
but of course not all the values therein provide exactly $6$ solutions.
Then you could proceed and examine the constant term of the Laurent series for
$$
\frac{1}
{{z^{\,6} \left( {1 - z^{\,7} } \right)\left( {1 - z^{\,9} } \right)}}
$$
Still another way is to resort to *Popoviciu's Theorem*, which in this case gives
$$
N(c) = \frac{c}
{{63}} - \left\{ {\frac{{4c}}
{9}} \right\} - \left\{ {\frac{{4c}}
{7}} \right\} + 1
$$
with $\left\{ x \right\} = x - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor $.
This provides an easiest way to compute the required min and max values for $c$ and also how many and which they are.

Now the problem you posed is known as "The Coin Exchange Problem of Frobenius"
and widely discussed in various papers, e.g. in [this paper](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/papers/frobeasy.slides.pdf) and in [this other paper](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/papers/frobnote.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a line of slope $-\frac{7}{9}$, initially extending through the origin and making its way "northeastward"—that is, sliding in the direction of positive $x$ and positive $y$.  As it does so, it traverses a lattice of points with non-negative integer coordinates.  (It will be simpler, computationally, to consider non-negative points, and the answer can be translated to positive points without much difficulty.)  G Cab's observation that additional solutions can be obtained from existing solutions is in fact exactly on point.

Consider that the *minimum* sum $c$ for which a given number of solutions exist can be obtained by considering those situations where a solution of the form $(0, y)$ and one of the form $(x, 0)$ both exist.  Simple consideration of the slope shows that we have $k+1$ solutions whenever the endpoint solutions are $(0, 7k)$ and $(9k, 0)$.  For instance, we have $6$ solutions for $k = 5$, which gives us $c = 9 \times 35 = 7 \times 45 = 315$.  This can be translated to the positive-point case simply by adding $315+7+9 = 331$.

The *maximum* sum $c$ for which a given number of solutions exist is a bit trickier, but note that we essentially want to "just miss" a solution to the left of the $y$-axis, and "just miss" another solution below the $x$-axis.  Since a solution at $x = 9$ means that we have a solution also at $x = 0$, we want our first solution to lie at $x = 8$, and then we have further solutions separated by intervals of length $9$: $x = 17, 26, 35, 44, 53$, and then we want to just miss a solution at $x = 62$.  That would-be solution would have $y = -1$, which means that the actual solutions, counting back toward the $y$-axis, would have intervals of length $7$: $y = 6, 13, 20, 27, 34, 41$.

Any of these solutions $(8, 41), (17, 34), \ldots, (53, 6)$ will yield the same maximum value of $c = 7 \times 8 + 9 \times 41 = 7 \times 17 + 9 \times 34 = \cdots = 425$.  The positive-point case can again be obtained by adding $425+7+9 = 441$.